# App signing page in google play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have been trying to upload my first app to google play console. I am stuck with the App signing page. Can you please walk through the steps to Export, encrypt, and upload my app signing private key. I am not sure how and where to run the command to run the tool, which will export and encrypt my private key.

Comment: which tool you are using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: I am using Android studio

Comment: So you want steps? to upload apk in google play store?

Comment: I have uploaded APK but I am not sure how to proceed with PEPK Tool. How to encrypt it and enroll my app

Answer (score 0):

When You create the build from the menu. There is an option which says Export encrypted key". Keep it checked and it will automatically generate your private key with PEPK tool encryption.

Build > Generate Signed Bundle / Apk > Select "Android App Bundle OR APK" 
and when you click next there is one check button which says "Export encrypted key" and your private key will be exported.

[image: Check the image attached]